# Manually save memgraph snapshot

Tags: memgraphdb

As said in `/etc/memgraph/memgraph.conf`:

```
# Storage snapshot creation interval (in seconds). Set to 0 to disable periodic
# snapshot creation. [uint64]
--storage-snapshot-interval-sec=300
```

Which means snapshots are made only automatically. Is there a way to manually run command to save snapshot in `/var/lib/memgraph/snapshots/` directory?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CREATE SNAPSHOT;` Cypher query to create a snapshot automatically. Read more about it in the [official documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/backup).